# Nav bar align: Logo on left, links on right

Tags: css, html

I'm having trouble getting the alignments right on a nav bar. I'm trying to figure out how to get the logo part to stay on the left of the nav bar, but put the links on the right side. I've tried using float: right but I can't seem to get it to work on just the links. How can I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/t46bcayd/1/

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/" class="logo">Logo</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: heard of pseudo classes? see this https://jsfiddle.net/t46bcayd/4/

Comment: perfect case for flexbox ... don't let float ruin your day

Answer (score 11):

Flexbox is perfect here...no need to change the structure, unless you want to.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}
nav {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 1em 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
nav ul li a.logo {
  background-color: green;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/" class="logo">Logo</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the inline-block rule for the list items you can float the first one left and the others right:

```
li {
    float: right;
}

li:first-child {
    float: left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t46bcayd/2/)**

You'd also need to re-order the list items that are floated right to:

```
<li><a href="http://google.com/" class="logo">Logo</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="http://google.com/">One</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `float:left` property

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}

nav {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    line-height: 3em;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a.logo {
    background-color: green;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/" class="logo">Logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com/">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I did have to change the order so they showed up right

Comment: That creates invalid HTML

Comment: A `<div>` can't be a child of a `<ul>`

Comment: I just realized that and I fixed it

Comment: Ok but now the order of the right nav is backwards. 3 2 1 instead of 1 2 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox for this.

```
<style>
    nav{
       display:flex;
       justify-content: space-between;
       align-items: center;
    }
</style>
<nav>
    <a href="http://google.com/" class="logo">Logo</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Remember prefixes** ... works in IE > 9