# How to change the text alignment in the toggle menu of bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align right the links items in the toggle menu of a bootstrap page, but it didn't work. By the way, the menu is left and logo is right, but need to align items to the right to be appear under the logo. any help?
[this is the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK6GD.png)
 this is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/logob.png" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle fl7" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Good First Question.

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163621/nav-bar-align-logo-on-left-links-on-right

Comment: I mean the alignment of items in the dropdown-menu in the mobile view. - @schaturv

Answer (score 2):

just add css `text-align:right` in li for mobile view

```
@media (max-width:767px){
   .nav>li{
       text-align:right
   }
}
```

```css
.logo{
  float:right;
  padding:5px 0;
  font-size:25px;
}


@media (max-width:767px){
   .nav>li{
       text-align:right
   }
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle{
       float:left;
       margin-left:15px;
   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/logob.png" alt="">Logo</a></div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle fl7" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: It didn't work ! note that in the normal case, the menu is in the left and logo at right,, see the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

I could not create the exact thing in the snippet as you didn't provide css. But this should do the job. Just add `class="text-right"` to your `a-tags` in `nav-links`.

**Example snippet**

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/logob.png" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle fl7" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a class="text-right" href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-right" href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-right" href="#">item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-right" href="#">item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a class="text-right" href="#">item 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't work ! just for explanation, you make the menu button to the right and list items also to the right, but in my project the menu button in the left corner and want the list item to appear in the right side. @neophyte

Comment: Add your css..it is not possible to recreate the problem if you don't make the css available.